# Problem adding leading zeros to a nested SELECT value using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add leading zeros to an nvarchar data type value that needs to be a length of 9 but I'm not having any luck with my attempts. I am building a flat file and every field is an nvarchar data type.

Here is my original SQL code:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX([Record Number])+1 FROM #tempFINAL) as [Record Number]
```

After doing some googling here is attempt #1:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9) + (SELECT MAX([Record Number]+1) FROM #tempFINAL), 9) as [Record Number]
```

Here is attempt #2:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + (SELECT MAX([Record Number]+1) FROM #tempFINAL), 9) as [Record Number]
```

Neither attempts worked.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  I must be missing something fairly easy.  Thanks.

Comment: That is because MAX(RecordNumber) returns an int. You need to convert that to nvarchar. But be careful, MAX() + 1 is very rarely a good approach. It might be ok in your situation since you seem to be using a temp table.

Comment: For a reference see [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).

Comment: Thank you guys.  I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sean is correct, your mixing a string with an int.  Here are 4 quick options:

```
Select [Record Number] = Format(max([Record Number])+1,'000000000') from #tempFINAL

Select [Record Number] = right(concat('000000000',max([Record Number])+1),9) from #tempFINAL

Select [Record Number] = right('000000000'+convert(varchar(10),max([Record Number])+1),9) from #tempFINAL

Select [Record Number] = right('000000000'+left(max([Record Number])+1,10),9) from #tempFINAL
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `+1` is implicitly converting `varchar` to `int` thus you are loosing leading zeros.

Try This:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CAST((max('28') + 1) AS VARCHAR(6)),6)

SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CAST((MAX([Record Number] + 1) AS VARCHAR(6)),6) from #tempFinal
```

---

> ```
> SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CAST((max('28') + 1) AS VARCHAR(6)),6)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 000029           |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CAST((max('852') + 1) AS VARCHAR(6)),6)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 000853           |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CAST((max('1945') + 1) AS VARCHAR(6)),6)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 001946           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d61b77279f3dedc15878f94048a7d73d)*